# Can I use subfunctions within control structures in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here is the program.

I need to do this using subfunctions.

```
%//To compute the area of circle,rectangle or volume of rectangle depending on the number of input arguments.

y=areavlme(a,b,c)    

%//For one input, the function finds the area for the circle
%//For two inputs, finds the area of rectangle
%//For three inputs, finds the volume of rectangle

if nargin<1
    disp('error');
elseif nargin==1
    function s = circarea(a);
        s=a*a;
elseif nargin==2
    function t =rectarea(a,b);
        t=a*b;
else
    function e=rectvolume(a,b,c);
        e=a*b*c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likewise I don't see the point but you could use anonymous functions.

```
circarea = @(x) pi*x*x;
rectarea = @(x,y) x*y;
rectvolume = @(x,y,z) x*y*z;

if nargin<1
    disp('error');
elseif nargin==1
    s=circarea(a);
elseif nargin==2
    t = rectarea(a,b);
else
    e = rectvolume(a,b,c);
```

Also your equation for the area of the circle will require pi, assuming that a is the radius.

Comment: Ya,that's right. But what is the use of anonymous functions.

Comment: @user3410944 E.g., you can use them in conjunction with `arrayfun()`, `cellfun()` etc., and wherever callback functions are used.

Comment: +1 because it works in a script as well. It won't *really* work in control structures though. You could define and immediately use the function whithin the `if`, but there's no practical use to that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point.

You have the following options:

- operate without functions:

  ```
  function y=areavlme(a,b,c)

  if nargin<1
      disp('error');
  elseif nargin==1
      y = a*a;
  elseif nargin==2
      y = a*b;
  else
      y = a*b*c;
  ```
- operate with functions, *and call them*:

  ```
  function y=areavlme(a,b,c)  

  if nargin<1
      disp('error');
  elseif nargin==1
      y = circarea(a);
  elseif nargin==2
      y = rectarea(a,b);
  else
      y = rectvolume(a,b,c);

  function s = circarea(a);
  s=a*a;

  function t =rectarea(a,b);
  t=a*b;

  function e=rectvolume(a,b,c);
  e=a*b*c;
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I got the first answer,ie, without using the sub functions. I was looking for the second one. I have one more doubt. In general, can we define sub-functions within control statements?

Comment: No. You cannot define functions inside control statements.

Comment: Actually you can sort of, anonymous functions can be defined inside control statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use nested functions, taking advantage of scoping to remove arguments in the function call

```
function y=areavlme(a,b,c)

%//For one input, the function finds the area for the circle
%//For two inputs, finds the area of rectangle
%//For three inputs, finds the volume of rectangle

function s = circarea
    s=a*a*pi;
end

function t =rectarea
    t=a*b;
end

function e=rectvolume
    e=a*b*c;
end


if nargin<1
    disp('error');
elseif nargin==1
    y=circarea;
elseif nargin==2
    y=rectarea;
else
    y=rectvolume;
end
end
```